# for some reason my put route is not working in sequelize

Tags: sql-update, sequelize.js, put

this is my call

```js
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/user_data",
            method: "PUT",
            data: {
                id: data.id,
                level: newLevel,
                point: addPoints
            },
            error: function(req, err) {
                console.log(err)
                
            }
        }).then(result => {
            
            console.log("user info updated");
            console.log(result);
            // window.location.replace("/members");
        });
```

this is my route

```js
  app.put("/api/user_data", function(req, res) {
    db.User.update(
      {
        points: req.body.points,
        level: req.body.level,
      },
      {
        where: {
          id: req.body.id,
        },
      }
    ).then(function(result) {
      res.json(result);
    });
  });
```

I am also getting an error saying "can't set headers after they are sent".

I had `{ force: true }` set before and it was not working. When I set force: false the level would update but only after I logged out then logged back in. I'm not sure why that was happening at all but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see you have a typo. In the request you have a property as point but in the route you use points.